# Trying to generating numbers and checking if they are equal but it's not working

Tags: java

```
class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    static JButton one;
    static JButton two;
    static JLabel magic;

    public void main() {
      JFrame frm = new JFrame("GUI INTRO");
      JPanel content = new JPanel();
      frm.add(content);
      
      one = new JButton(" ");
      two = new JButton(" ");

      one.addActionListener(this);
      two.addActionListener(this);

      content.add(one);
      content.add(two);
      
      frm.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
      frm.setSize(700,700);
      frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
      frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frm.setVisible(true);
    }
  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      int x = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
      String y = Integer.toString(x);
  
      int w = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
      String z = Integer.toString(w);
      if(e.getSource() == A) // irrelivant
        magic.setText("MAGIC"); // irrelivant
      else if (e.getSource() == one) {
        one.setText(y);
        System.out.print(x);
        if(x==w) {
          System.out.println("You Win the Big Prize!");
        }
      }
      else if (e.getSource() == two) {
        two.setText(z);
        System.out.print(w);
        if(x==w) {
          System.out.println("You Win the Big Prize!");
        }
      }
     }
     public static void main(String[] args){
        Main frame = new Main();
        frame.main();
      }
     }
```

After each button is clicked a random number becomes its name. The goal is that when both of the buttons are equivalent a print statement will print. I have tried printing the actual variables and they match up with what's on the button but for some reason, the if statement that compares them doesn't work properly.

Comment: What is `e`?  What is `one`?  What is `y`? What is `x`?  What is `w`?  What is `two`?  What is `z`?

Comment: one - connected to the first empty button    two - connected to the second button      x - connected to a generated  variable w - connected to a different generated variable z - int w converted to a string y - x converted to a string

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare `String`s, use `String#equals`

Comment: when they match up on the buttons, that's not when they match up in the x==w. On the buttons you are only seeing the latest value of whichever button was clicked. However, according to the logic, you could still get the "You Win the Big Prize!", It just might not happen when you see equal values on the button.

Comment: *After each button is clicked a random number becomes its name* That's not an accurate description. The *first* thing that happens *on each click*  is that *two* random numbers are generated. Think about that. @levangode has already pointed to the fact that what you intend to happen has not been reflected in your code

Answer (score 0):

> but for some reason, the if statement that compares them doesn't work
> properly.

Because you *never* compare the values assigned to the buttons.  You actually generate two values when you click a button.  One of those values is assigned to a button but the other is just some meaningless value.  But you compare *those* generated values rather than the buttons.

```
  int x = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
  ...
  int w = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
  ...
    if(x==w) {
      System.out.println("You Win the Big Prize!");
    }
  ...
    if(x==w) {
      System.out.println("You Win the Big Prize!");
    }
  ...
```

1. Generate a single value
2. Assign that value to the appropriate button
3. Compare the button values.

Something like..

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (e.getSource().equals(one)) {
    one.setText(generateRandomValue());
    testEquals(one, two);
  } else if (e.getSource().equals(two) {
    two.setText(generateRandomValue());
    testEquals(one, two);
  }
}
```

Comment: I figured it out thanks! I generated the random numbers within the if statements and declared the variables under Main.